# Помогите модифицировать скрипт

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт выпадающего списка с чекбоксами. Все хорошо, неудобно только одно - как сделать так, чтобы при потере фокуса списка, список закрывался. Например по щелчку в любое место страницы список должен закрыться.

```js
var expanded = false;



function showCheckboxes() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
  if (!expanded) {
    checkboxes.style.display = "block";
    expanded = true;
  } else {
    checkboxes.style.display = "none";
    expanded = false;
  }
  
}
```

```css
.multiselect {
  width: 200px;
}

.selectBox {
  position: relative;
}

.selectBox select {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.overSelect {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#checkboxes {
  display: none;
  border: 1px #dadada solid;
}

#checkboxes label {
  display: block;
}

#checkboxes label:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
  <div class="multiselect">
    <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes();">
      <select>
        <option>Select an option</option>
      </select>
      <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="checkboxes">
      <label for="one">
        <input type="checkbox" id="one" />First checkbox</label>
      <label for="two">
        <input type="checkbox" id="two" />Second checkbox</label>
      <label for="three">
        <input type="checkbox" id="three" />Third checkbox</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: в вопрос код добавьте, ссылка может устареть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { 

  var expanded = false,
      container = document.getElementsByClassName("multiselect")[0],
      checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
  
  container.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (!expanded) {
      checkboxes.style.display = "block";
      expanded = true;
    } else {
      checkboxes.style.display = "none";
      expanded = false;
    }
  });
  
  document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var isClickInside = container.contains(event.target);
    if (!isClickInside) {
      checkboxes.style.display = "none";
      expanded = false;
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.multiselect {
  width: 200px;
}

.selectBox {
  position: relative;
}

.selectBox select {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.overSelect {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#checkboxes {
  display: none;
  border: 1px #dadada solid;
}

#checkboxes label {
  display: block;
}

#checkboxes label:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <div class="multiselect">
      <div class="selectBox">
        <select>
          <option>Select an option</option>
        </select>
        <div class="overSelect"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="checkboxes">
        <label for="one">
        <input type="checkbox" id="one" />First checkbox</label>
        <label for="two">
        <input type="checkbox" id="two" />Second checkbox</label>
        <label for="three">
        <input type="checkbox" id="three" />Third checkbox</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: (((( Ничего не понимаю. Здесь все работает. Переношу в html страницу только эти куски кода, в соответствующие теги <script></script> и <style></style> - не работает. Вообще ничего, даже не открывается меню. (((

Comment: Причем, если убрать checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes") то в JS Bin, все продолжает работать, а вот в html файле меню тоже работает, но не закрывается если теряет фокус.
Еще заметил штуку, что в некоторых случаях, чтобы меню открылось нужно нажать на него дважды. Google Chrome 68.0.3440.106, 64 бит, Linux

Comment: @Алексей, починил последнюю "штуку"

Comment: @vp_arth, спасибо за дополнение) только в отладчике добавил)

Comment: @Алексей, у меня в JS Bin тоже все работает. http://jsbin.com/safewugila/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: За "штуку" - спасибо ))))) У меня в отладчике тоже все отлично работает. Мне то надо не в отладчике. ;) ну не поленитесь - кто-нибудь, перенесите в обычный HTML файл и просто откройте в браузере пожалуйста.  Может это я такой неудачник и только у меня не работает.  Проверил в FireFox та же ерунда.

Comment: Оооо!!! Ура!!! С поправленной "штукой" все заработало!!! Парни - огромное спасибо!!! Буду должен! Вообще все четко работает!

Comment: @Алексей, если ответ вам помог, отметьте его принятым, жмякните галочку.

Comment: @Haswell, пометил! Спасибо еще раз! Кто интересно мне репутацию скинул. Я же не виноват, что больше в Perl программирую, а не в javascript. )))

Comment: @Алексей, вы не узнаете, кто) сколько людей столько и мнений, не парьтесь на счет этого, успехов.